# Slick batch insert (for Redshift JDBC)

Tags: scala, amazon-redshift, slick

Using `++=` in Slick results in one `insert` statement per row for Redshift. Is there a way to make it use [the bulk insert syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-multi-row-inserts.html)?

```
insert into category_stage values
(default, default, default, default),
(20, default, 'Country', default),
(21, 'Concerts', 'Rock', default);
```

Comment: It will do bulk inserts also. What exactly do you want?

Comment: @MaheshChand I want to insert multiple rows in one query, instead of one query per row, does this help?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard PostgreSQL Profile and driver, there is an option to re-write inserts to bulk syntax.

Add the parameter `?reWriteBatchedInserts=true` to the JDBC connection URL. It's described in [Connecting to the Database](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html#connection-parameters) part of the PostgreSQL documentation.

A while back [I tried it out against PostgreSQL](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1272#issuecomment-208247574) and it worked well. Hopefully it will work for you with Redshift.